# Python Paste script crashes with big template file?

Tags: python, crash, paste, pyramid, chameleon

I have a Pyramid application that uses Chameleon as its template engine.
I have one (quite large, but I have had larger) template that will just not work.
Whenever I try to render it to return as a view, paste server development.ini crashes miserably without any errors (Mac OS X's terminal tells me "bus error").
When I run the exact same code on my server with apache and mod_wsgi, everything works great.

How do I even start figuring out whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Start by installing [yolk](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk) so that you can list the versions of all the python packages you have installed with `yolk -l`.

Next, you should post your template to [gist](http://gist.github.com/) or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) so people can see the template you're working with and try to reproduce the problem. In fact, it would be even more helpful if you can provide a simplified version of the Pyramid app that reproduces it on your side.